# Default Gateway IP For Whole Network Changed Itself

Tags: networking, dhcp, gateway

I have been running a local area network. The scenario is I have one main CISCO SG300-28 switch through which all traffic passes. I also have connected 3 TP-LINK device to create some wireless connection.

I have LAN IP gateway address of `192.168.1.1`, but the other day when I came into my office, I was surprised to see that the gateway changed to `192.168.0.254` for whole network. My ISP provider said that it is due to DHCP on any of 3 TP-LINK devices connected to my network (they have their on LAN IP 192.168.0.1).

Kindly guide me how this happened and how can I avoid this from happening again.

Comment: Have you disabled DHCP on your access points?

Comment: Yeah I have disabled DHCP on AP's but after devices didn't connect to router .

Answer (score 1):

Simple soultion is disable the DHCP server on the TP-Link devices when you get them.

If you need to disable them now either plug each tp-link device into another switch, (one at a time), and connect into via the web iterface or set you ip staticly within the tp-link address range add connect that way. Just ensure to only have one plugged in at a time until you have change the address settings otherwise it can get a little fun.

Comment: But the thing is, how IP would be generated for communicating devices if I disable DHCP server ?????I have tried this and then sink devices coudn't connect to that TP-Link router

Comment: You should set the access points to have a static IP and have the router handle DHCP

Comment: Thank You ITAIfs, Lemme try this solution and will get back to you.